# Изменить вид кнопки в HTML

Tags: html, css

Как убрать эту квадратную обводку вокруг плюса? Хочу изменить стандартную кнопку на такой плюсик.

```css
.button {
    background: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-elements/32/add-circle-24.png');
    background-size: contain;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<button class='button'></button>
```

[image: Фото кнопки]

Comment: это же обводка от картинки, ее нельзя убрать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Просто обнулите `border` и `outline`

```css
.button {
    background: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-elements/32/add-circle-24.png');
    background-size: contain;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое сработало)Но я нуб и у меня сразу еще один вопрос, как сделать так что бы при нажатии отрабатывалась такая же анимация на картинке как и при нажатии на обычную кнопку, или просто в css менять цвет при нажатии?

Comment: Стилями, селектором .button:active {}

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button{
  background: transparent url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-elements/32/add-circle-24.png');
  background-size: contain;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="button"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

border-radius: 50%; в идентификатор

Answer (score 0):

`button { border: transparent; }`

`button:focus-visible { outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px; }`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]